# Avatar fetching using Meteor and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using the following snippet to insert the link to the OP's avatar to the post.

#### posts.js (part of it)

```
var post = _.extend(postAttributes, {
        userId: user._id, 
        author: user.username || user.profile.name, 
        submitted: new Date(),
        authorAvatar: user.profile.avatar,
        commentsCount: 0,
        answersCount:0,
        upvoters: [], 
        votes: 0
    });
```

The only problem with this was that if the OP changes his/her avatar, the avatar showing on the post would not change.

So, I was wondering if I could access the links to the OP's avatar right away from template.helpers.

Or, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you post more code around your function or Spacebars helper? I think you don't register a reactive dependency on the user, that's why it is not updating. You could register such a dependency by getting the user object with `Meteor.users.findOne(user._id)`

Comment: Right now I'm fetching the OP's avatar by putting something like this. ```<img src={{authorAvatar}}>```. @imslavko

Comment: @imslavko What I'm trying to achieve is get the userId from the post attributes, then use that to find the OP, then access OP's avatar by using ```.profile.avatar```

Comment: @imslavko I figured this out! ```return Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId}).profile.avatar;```